# getcontentpane()

Tags: java, eclipse

I have come back to Java after ten years and I am starting again from the beginning.

I tried some code taken from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java

```
import javax.swing.*;        

public class HelloWorldGraphical {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(I took off comments.)

I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, version: Helios Service Release 1, and the JRE 1.8 libraries.

The package is the default one.

My error message is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:  getcontentpane()

and only it seems to be a compile error.

I don't understand.

Comment: The code you posted says `getContentPane()`. Your error says `getcontentpane()`. One is correct. The other is wrong. Which one is in your actual code?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

Comment: writing error, sorry

Comment: it says as well :The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.swing.JComponent. Fix the build path then try building this project. But the path seems to be good. And too : " The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: I don't see any error when I compile your code.

Comment: I thought it would work too

Comment: @BrainUnderflow Your comment is a different problem. Your question is just a syntax problem.

Comment: found this other error message :  "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JLabel)"

Comment: 'But the path seems to be good.' How so? Which JRE is the project compiling against?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it : my version was Helios.
I thought it was the latest. 
I installed Mars version, with the same JRE.

Config problem.
New newbie error
Sorry for disturbing.